# Parsing part of a XML file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

After receiving "day" from a text input, how can I display the `<product>` of the `<availabilities>`, ONLY from the same date using jQuery? Maybe with the use of `.siblings()` ?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-15'?>
<timetable>
  <date>
    <day>22-01-2013</day>
    <availabilities>
      <availability>
        <starttime>10:00</starttime>
        <endtime>13:00</endtime>
        <startplace>Funchal</startplace>
        <endplace>Funchal</endplace>
        <resource>Excursões na Madeira</resource>
        <idstartplace>18</idstartplace>
        <idendplace>18</idendplace>
        <idperiodoconsumo>13289</idperiodoconsumo>
        <idproduct>23</idproduct>
        <product>EXC_SANT</product>
        <idtimeperiod>11523</idtimeperiod>
        <idavailability>3561</idavailability>
      </availability>
      <availability>
        <starttime>10:00</starttime>
        <endtime>13:00</endtime>
        <startplace>Funchal</startplace>
        <endplace>Funchal</endplace>
        <resource>Excursões na Madeira</resource>
        <idstartplace>18</idstartplace>
        <idendplace>18</idendplace>
        <idperiodoconsumo>13290</idperiodoconsumo>
        <idproduct>33</idproduct>
        <product>foot</product>
        <idtimeperiod>11524</idtimeperiod>
        <idavailability>3593</idavailability>
      </availability>
      <availability>
        <starttime>10:00</starttime>
        <endtime>13:00</endtime>
        <startplace>Funchal</startplace>
        <endplace>Funchal</endplace>
        <resource>Excursões na Madeira</resource>
        <idstartplace>18</idstartplace>
        <idendplace>18</idendplace>
        <idperiodoconsumo>13289</idperiodoconsumo>
        <idproduct>22</idproduct>
        <product>VLT_ILHA</product>
        <idtimeperiod>11523</idtimeperiod>
        <idavailability>3561</idavailability>
      </availability>
    </availabilities>
  </date>
  <date>
      ...
      </date> 
...
```

Here's my sucess: function:

```
function parseStuff(data){
    $(data).find('date').each(function(){
        var day = $(this).find('day').text();

        if (day==decodeURI(iHash[3])){
            alert('Date matches!');
        }
    });
}
```

I'd appreciate some help, I have no idea how to do this.. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var product = $(this).find('product').text();
```

i think you have to put this here:

```
if (day==decodeURI(iHash[3])){
  var product = $(this).find('product').text();
  alert('Date matches!');
}
```

Comment: That will display every `<product>` from the XML file. I only want those whose parent is the matching date - and that's my problem!

Comment: you can try putting that in if condition where it matches

Comment: I though that would return just 1 product... *facepalm* Thank You!

Comment: and how can I find, for example,  the `<starttime>`, which is a sibling of `<product>`?

Comment: `$(this).find('starttime').text();` May be this way, depends where you want this to read.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
function parseStuff(data,toBeMatchedDate){

    productList=array();

    $(data).find('date').each(function(){


        var day = $(this).find('day').text();

        if (day==decodeURI(iHash[3]) && day==toBeMatchedDate)   //if date is matched
        {

             xmlProdcutList=$(this).find('product'); //all the products associated with this date


             $.each(function(i,thisProduct){
                         productList.push(thisProduct.text()); //store in the main array
               });

return productList;


        }
    });
}
```